# How to display a <div> on hover on another <div>

Tags: css, html

i Have used bootstrap and css , here is my code

```
<div class = "row" id="parent"=>

  <div class="col-md-8" id="ClildDiv1">

  //Some Content

</div>

<div class="col-md-4" id="ChildDiv2" style="display:none">

  //Some Content

<div>

</div>
```

Now i want on hover on 
`<div class="row Parent>`
All its Child  should be visible in this case 
`<div class="col-md-4 ChildDiv2">`

Any Help Would Be Appreciated And i want to achieve that only by CSS styling

Comment: The code you've shared is not good enough for this question - the tags don't even match

Comment: This question has been asked at least 30 times on this site in the CSS tag alone. Please search a little harder next time! :-)

Comment: oops , but i got my answer , thanks to all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want one of the sibling selectors.  General sibling `~` or next sibling `+`

```
.ClildDiv1:hover ~ .ChildDiv2 {
    display: block;
}
```

See [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/0ow5qmvh/)

Or, the parent hover for any child div would be

```
.Parent:hover > div {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: `.Parent:hover > div` saves my time , Thanks for it !!